# Difference between USING and ON when joining more than two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have three tables with the following data in them:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  movie_id INT,
  movie_name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id)
);
CREATE TABLE movie_ratings (
  movie_rating_id INT,
  movie_id INT,
  rating_value TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_rating_id),
  KEY movie_id (movie_id)
);
CREATE TABLE movie_actors (
  movie_actor_id INT,
  movie_id INT,
  actor_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_actor_id),
  KEY movie_id (movie_id)
);
INSERT INTO movies VALUES (1, 'Titanic'),(2,'Star Trek');
INSERT INTO movie_ratings VALUES (1,1,5),(2,1,4),(3,1,5);
INSERT INTO movie_actors VALUES (1,1,2),(2,2,2);
```

If I wanted to get the average rating and number of actors for each movie, I could do this using `JOINs`:

```
SELECT m.movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS avgRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Let's call that query A. Query A can be rewritten with `USING` thusly:

```
SELECT m.movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS avgRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r USING (movie_id)
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a USING (movie_id)
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Let's call that query B.

Both of those queries return 1 as numActors for the movie 'Star Trek'. So let's modify that query a bit:

```
SELECT m.movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS avgRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Let's call this query C. Instead of doing `m.movie_id = a.movie_id` I'm now doing `r.movie_id = a.movie_id`. For query C numActors is 0.

My questions are:

1. How can I write query C using `USING`? Can I?
2. Is `USING` essentially doing an `ON` with the current table and the table mentioned in `FROM`?
3. If the answer to #2 is yes then what does `USING` do when an implicit `JOIN` is used and multiple tables are in the `FROM`?

Comment: `movies.movie_id`.  How very smurf naming of you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Can C be rewritten using USING?

Yes, you can, using a nested join:

```
SELECT m.movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS avgRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN (
  movie_ratings r 
  LEFT JOIN movie_actors a USING (movie_id)
) USING (movie_id)
GROUP BY m.movie_id
```

### 2. Is USING essentially doing an ON with the current table and the table mentioned in FROM?

No. [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) says:

> The evaluation of multi-way natural joins differs in a very important way that affects the result of NATURAL or USING joins and that can require query rewriting. Suppose that you have three tables t1(a,b), t2(c,b), and t3(a,c) that each have one row: t1(1,2), t2(10,2), and t3(7,10). Suppose also that you have this NATURAL JOIN on the three tables:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2 NATURAL JOIN t3;
>
> Previously, the left operand of the second join was considered to be t2, whereas it should be the nested join (t1 NATURAL JOIN t2). As a result, the columns of t3 are checked for common columns only in t2, and, if t3 has common columns with t1, these columns are not used as equi-join columns. Thus, previously, the preceding query was transformed to the following equi-join:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1, t2, t3
>     WHERE t1.b = t2.b AND t2.c = t3.c;

So basically, in older versions of MySQL your query B was not the same as query A, but as query C!

### 3. What does USING do when an implicit JOIN is used and multiple tables are in the FROM?

Again, citing the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.

It's all about join-order and precedence. So basically `t1, t2 JOIN t3 USING (x)` would do `t2 JOIN t3 USING(x)` first and join that with `t1`.

Comment: op never use natural joins or implicit joins. I think he just wants to know what will happen if he uses `USING` with an implicit join.

Comment: @FOrguesR - I imagine the order of precedence would apply regardless of whether or not you were doing a NATURAL JOIN or a JOIN. And although I didn't use implicit JOINs I did ask about them in question #3.

Comment: @ForguesR Natural Joins and Joins with USING behave the same way: They have to implicitly choose two tables to compare. The MySQL docs talk about both of them in the first sentence, but then illustrate that with a Natural Join example. So this applies for USING as well.

Comment: @neubert The order of precedence applies to all of the Joins of course. Result-wise there would be no difference for an implicit or inner Join in our case, even if this order would be changed. For Outer (Left/Right) Joins, however, this order would change the result set: This is exactly what happened between query B and C* (the one in my answer with USING).

Answer (score 3):

If the column name is the same in both tables then yes, you can use `USING()`.

In other words, this:

```
SELECT movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS averageRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Is the same as:

```
SELECT movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS averageRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings USING (movie_id)
LEFT JOIN movie_actors USING (movie_id)
GROUP BY movie_id;
```

As far as the ambiguity there won't be any here. It will join the tables when the movie_id is equal. In your select statement, you are pulling the movie_name, which only exists in one column.

However, if you said this:

```
SELECT movie_id, AVG(rating_value) AS averageRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
```

MySQL will say there is an error because movie_id cannot be resolved because it as ambiguous. To fix this ambiguity, you'd just have to make sure you used a table alias or name when selecting movie_id.

This is a valid select statement:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, AVG(rating_value) AS averageRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
```

No error would be thrown for this.

I would like to comment that I foresee some danger here. If you left join movies with all of these tables, you could potentially receive null values. If movie_id 1 does not have any ratings, your AVG(rating_value) will return null. You won't have this problem for COUNT(actor_id) as this will just return 0. I don't know if this bothers you, but be aware that that column could return null.

I built the sample tables in MySQL workbench, and I'm unable to get SQL Fiddle to work to show you, but if you would like to see the data I've created let me know and I will edit the question.

Comment: Good point about the errors thrown. A followup question tho: So what if I wanted to do `LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id`? Would that be possible with ON or would I have to make use of a LEFT JOIN to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Assuming that full statement is `movie_ratings r LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id` yes that is a valid statement.

Comment: Err...  I mistyped. I meant...  can that be done with `USING`.

Comment: Yes. USING and ON can be used interchangeably, _assuming the column name is the same in both tables_. For example, if in one table it was just `id` and in the other it was `movie_id` you **need** to use `ON t1.id = t2.movie_id`.

Comment: So `ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id` is the same as `USING (movie_id)` and `ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id` is the same as `USING (movie_id)` but `ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id` and `ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id` are not the same thing. In particular, `ON r.movie_id = a.movie_id` won't include movies that have no actors in them. So what gives?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full select statement for the `r.movie_id = a.movie_id` example? Maybe the problem is elsewhere in the query and I'm just not able to picture this properly.

Comment: I think the reason for the failure is because you're ultimately left joining with movies m, so you should use m.movie_id in each of your `ON` statements. That's the only difference I see. Also, rewriting query C with USING would be the same as query B now.

Comment: At this point, @neubert I may be missing the question. You have a working query, so what are you still looking for?

Comment: I want some clarification on what `USING` is doing. Quoting my question, "Is USING essentially doing an ON with the current table and the table mentioned in FROM? And if that is the case then what does USING do when an implicit JOIN is used and multiple tables are in the FROM?"

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity as USING applies to the tables in the join so this query

```
SELECT movie_name, AVG(rating_value), COUNT(actor_id)
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r USING (movie_id)
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a USING (movie_id)
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

is pretty much equivalent to the one with inner joins except that the `movie_id`column should only appear once in the results, instead of three times in the`inner join`case.

See this example for the column elimination:  http://ideone.com/qMj5XK (using SQLite I think, SQL Fiddle wouldn't work but MySQL should behave in the same way).

Comment: Tested this in MySQL for you - works fine. SQL Fiddle down for me as well.

Comment: The `movie_id` column will appear once only if you use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @ForguesR just noticed that the question has changed and a bounty was attached after I posted my answer, guess I'll have to update it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write query C using USING? Can I?

Like jpw mentionned in is answer **yes** you can use `USING` with query C.  It will join `m` with `r`using `movie_id` and `m` with `a` also using `movie_id`.  In fact `USING` with MySQL is aligned with the SQL 2003 standard.

> Is USING essentially doing an ON with the current table and the table
>   mentioned in FROM?

**Yes** `USING` is doing an ON with the current table and the table mentioned in the `FROM` clause.  The only difference is the number columns you are going to end with if you use an asterisk in the `SELECT` clause.  The Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljusing.html) for `USING` is much more helpful than the MySQL documentation about that.

> If the answer to #2 is yes then what does USING do when an implicit 
>   JOIN is used and multiple tables are in the FROM?

You can try it for yourself but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't work with an implicit join (`FROM tableA, tableB`).  This might be just another reason why implicit joins should be avoided.

Also since `USING` can only be used with explicit join that would mean a very awkward query mixing both explicit and implicit join.  Something you probably want to avoid.

**Edit :**

By the way, `numActors` is 0 in query C because your join are incorrect.  In fact if there are no movie rating then there are no actors!  If you fix that you should get the same result than query B.

```
SELECT m.movie_name, AVG(rating_value) AS avgRating, COUNT(actor_id) AS numActors
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN movie_ratings r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
LEFT JOIN movie_actors a ON m.movie_id = a.movie_id -- Instead of r.movie_id = a.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Comment: The query is correct and the JOIN in query C is written as intended. The tables and the query are all contrived and in this contrived example it may not make a lot of sense but it is just an example. Applying the change you suggested to query C makes query C and query A the same, which isn't that helpful for illustrating my question.

Comment: Then you should have a look at wolfgangwalther answer if you really want to use `USING` in your doesn't-make-sense query C but, obviously, you shouldn't.  Basically `USING` is a shortcut.  If it fits your needs and makes things clearer because it is shorter then use it.  If not, be explicit and stick to `LEFT JOIN ON`.